# How to uncheck a checkbox bound to a vuex store state array item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, buefy

I'm working on a feature wherein users have a list of priorities and they can mark priorities as completed by checking a checkbox (image below for reference).

[list of priorities with checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNh4X.png)

Before proceeding to complete/finish a priority, I ask for a confirmation using a dialog box. Users can click "ok" to proceed or "cancel" to close the dialog box and not proceed with the action. I have completed the "ok" part, but for "cancel", I need the checkbox to remain unchecked (or at least make it look like it remained unchecked). To handle this, I pass the `$event` object to the `@change` event handler and set the target value to false when the dialog box is cancelled: `evt.target.value = false;`

I'm skeptical about this solution, because I don't think it's correct to set the value of the event target in the view model, but I can't think of a different way. Is there another way to handle this scenario?

My template/code is something like this (simplified):

```
<ul>
  <li :key="item.id" v-for="(item, index) in priorities">
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        :checked="item.isCompleted"
        @change="handleComplete(item, $event)"
      />
      <div>
        <a href="#">{{ item.title }}</a>
        <p class="subtitle is-7">{{ item.targetDateTime | short }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>
      <fa :icon="['fas', 'minus-circle']" />
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
export default {
  name: "PriorityList",
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      priorities: state => state.priorities
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      confirmComplete: "confirmComplete"
    }),
    handleComplete(priority, evt) {
      this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: "Confirm",
        message: "This action cannot be undone from the priorities list. Do you want to continue?",
        type: "is-danger",
        size: "is-small",
        onConfirm: async () => {
            // item.isCompleted is mutated in the confirmComplete() action
            await this.confirmComplete(priority);
        },
        onCancel: () => {
            // TODO: A different solution to uncheck checkbox
            evt.target.value = false; // current solution
        }
      });
    },
  }
};
```

Note: I'm not using `v-model` in the checkbox since it's bound to an array item from a vuex store which will throw an error (do not mutate a state outside a mutation) when the checkbox value changes.

Answer (score 0):

### binding to the input with v-model

```js
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="item.isCompleted"
    @input="handleComplete(index)"
      />
```

### handle checkbox state change with method

```js
handleComplete(index) {
      this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: "Confirm",
        message: "This action cannot be undone from the priorities list. Do you want to continue?",
        type: "is-danger",
        size: "is-small",
        onConfirm: async () => {
            // I suppose this is mutating the state and that the store will get updated automatically then
            await this.confirmComplete(this.priorities[index]);
        },
        onCancel: () => {
            // TODO: use store actions to mutate state
            this.priorities[index] = false
        }
      });
    },
```

Main part was about the template binding

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. The checkbox  was checked once I clicked it and no way to revert when I cancelled the dialog box.

Comment: so you're trying to revert it ?
in that case, take the index instead of the item

```js
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="item.isCompleted"
    @input="handleComplete(index)"
      />
```

```js
// handleComplete (index)
onConfirm: () => this.confirmComplete(this.priorities[index])

onCancel: () => this.priorities[index] = false
```


** It's a very bad practice to mutate the state directly ***
Consider creating an action to toggle the priority

Comment: I am aware not to mutate the state outside a mutation that’s why I mentioned in my post that I did not use `v-model` and instead used `:checked` and `@change`. The problem I am facing is whether I commit the state change of `item.isComplete` through the `confirmComplete` action by clicking the `ok` button on the dialog box or do nothing by cancelling the dialog box, the checkbox remains checked. And my work around is to set `evt.target.value = false` to uncheck (or revert the value of) the checkbox when `cancel` is clicked. Is there another way instead of setting `evt.target.value` directly?

Comment: This is exactly what I did based on your suggested solution: I replaced `:checked` with `:value`, replace `@change` with `@input`. Then I added a mutation: `setNotCompleted(state, index) { state.priorities[index].isCompleted = false; }`. I invoke this mutation `onCancel` of the dialog box. It didn't work.